# Ruby On Rails: pluralize for other languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, customization

I am building apps for a non-english audience. Right now, I use english nouns to name my models, yet I prefer to use native dutch ones. As the convention uses the plural of the class name for tables, I assume it is the pluralize method inside Rails (where it resides, I wouldn't know). How can I change the pluralize method and where is it located? Would this break Rails?

I am using Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.8.7

Example:
The Book class becomes **books** now.
My Boek class becomes **boeks**, but it is grammatically correct to use **boeken**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add your rules to an *inflections.rb* file in config/initializers. See the [API documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections):

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'boek', 'boeken'
end
```

Comment: I remember briefly tapping into inflections to pluralize for my native language... it was chaos, irregularity all over the place. ^^

Comment: I see here (http://www.dutchgrammar.com/en/?n=NounsAndArticles.11) that the -en termination is the regular one. You should be able to code the default rule with .plural and .singular, then follow it by irregular plurals.

Comment: I'd probably try googling to see if anyone has already created an inflections.rb for Dutch. No need for people to get things wrong more than once! :)

Comment: I wonder why the inflections aren't separated by languages! What if I have a word "bla" in both languages english and latin, and in english the pluralization should be "blas" and in latin it should be "blae"?

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim It probably wasn't done because the whole thing was a bad idea from the start.  There's a point where convention over configuration creeps into "also weird habits I have which I get tired of having to manually deal with".  Pre-Rails, common database design used singular table names.  The person table is where you store a person.  You can store more than one person, but it is still a "person" table.  Funny though that in Rails you still say Person.where() instead of People.where(), even though you may get multiple persons returned.  Ergo, plural table names is half-baked.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps won't help you because you want Dutch language, but for Spanish, French, Kazakh, Turkish or Norwegian, there is this:

https://github.com/davidcelis/inflections

Comment: Dutch is a strange language. There's a plural on -s and one on -en. The choice between the two is quite arbitrary, though it can be put into several rules (although the rule can depend on the meaning of the word).

Next to that, the final syllable of the word is often modified too. Like School > Scholen loses an "o", and Ton > Tonnen gains an "n".

Many foreighners never get the pluralisation correct. And even natives can get the rules wrong for uncommon words. It also doesn't help that some dialects have other rules.

Comment: @sanderd17 English has as many or more seemingly arbitrary inconsistencies.  Some of them are due to different groups having different pronunciations, and the first group to write it their way the most "won".  More often, it is because of where the word came from (usually another or neighbor language).  English has a few words which are made plural with '-en'.  See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180564/etymology-of-certain-words-ending-in-en

Answer (score 2):

In addition, as far as views are concerned my preferred way of dealing with pluralizing foreign strings is **i18n pluralization**. Take a look at a straightforward example below.

```
# config/locales/en.yml

en:
  message:
    one: You have 1 message #Your foreign string
    other: You have %{count} messages #Your foreign string
```

Then in view you can do

```
# app/views/messages/index.html.erb

<%= t("message", count: current_user.messages.count) %>
```

Check [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization).
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is not answering the question specifically, but if a language has too much irregularities one can disable the inflector according to the [discussion](http://lists.rubyonrails.org/pipermail/rails/2004-December/000960.html).

`ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false`