# In a show action, how to list objects that are in a associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I want to do here is to list the entries of each activities in the project.

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb :

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @projects = Project.all
    end

    def show
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
        @activities = @project.activities
    end
end
```

app/views/projects/show.html.erb :

```
  <div>
    <p><%= @project.description %></p>

    <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
      <div>
        <p><%= activity.name %></p>

        <% activity.entries.each do |entry| %>  <= the error is at this line
            <p><%= entry.name %></p>
        <% end %>

      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

My models are :

- Project : has many activities
- Activity : has many entries, belongs to project
- Entry : belong to activity

The error I obtain when I run it :
"uninitialized constant Activity::Saisy" on the show file

I don't know if I can put an each loop inside an other each loop ? Maybe that's the problem, but I can't find an other way to do it...

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `Saisy`? Is that word mentioned anywhere in your code?

Comment: Thanks. You've find the problem.
In fact, I've posted an english version of my french app where "Saisie" is the french word for "Entry".
But for Rails, the word "Saisies" is the plural of "Saisy", which was not the case in my app.
Now I've translated my app in the Shakespear's language, all is running good.

Comment: I've just find out there is a solution to the pluralizing problem whith other languages : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998551/ruby-on-rails-pluralize-for-other-languages

Comment: Yeah, per [Ruby Community Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming): "Name identifiers in English". This is especially important in Rails, where tons of conventions are used.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the ruby style guide. I don't knew it.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming `activity` to `a`, maybe `activity` is reserved work

```
 <div>
    <p><%= @project.description %></p>

    <% @activities.each do |a| %>
     <div>
      <p><%= a.name %></p>

      <% a.entries.each do |entry| %>
         <p><%= entry.name %></p>
      <% end %>
     </div>   
   <% end %>
</div>
```